# Assigning rownames to DataFrames using DeployR in C#

Tags: c#, r, dataframe, revolution-r

I am using `DeployR` library to interface with R from C# .Net.

I am currently in the process of implementing DataFrames. I could create DataFrames with rows being numbered as 1,2,3.., but my requirement is to provide names to rows as it is supported with DataFrames in R. How to achieve this?

For example, I have my model has `EmpId`, `Empname`, `EmpSalary`, `Age`, `DepartmentName`. 
How to reference the rows in this dataframe using `EmpName`?

Thanks,
Shiras

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Are you using standard `R` `data.frame`?  Does this have anything to do `DeployR`? etc.  Just clarify a bit on what you are tying to do.

Comment: Yes, I am using standard R data.frame. What I am trying to achieve is  create a dataframe from C# and invoke a RScript by passing this dataframe. Hence DeployR is required in my case. I am able to do all this. However, I am not able set the rownames as I desire, instead dataframes shows the rownames as 1,2,3 etc.